# Agora.io issue in Reactjs and React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, video-streaming, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I have the next problem, I have a Mobile app that will be using for the users. A web app that will be using for the admin. I already develop both apps but I have a problem, I don't have a way to know who user is connected.

Both app are working with Firebase, users and admin are in the same Channel but I don't found a way to know which user is online.

React Native: https://github.com/syanbo/react-native-agora#readme
Reactjs: https://github.com/jjrajani/react-agora.io

Please, help me. Thanks. I want a way to assign an unique ID to each user (mobile app) and get those ID inside of web app.

PD:
The users will have the camera opened everytime and they can't listen or watch the others members (including admin). Just the admin can watch and listen to everybody but the admin needs to have a way to know which user is connected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign unique uids to each user inside the join channel method both [Web](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.client.html#join) and [React Native](https://syanbo.github.io/react-native-agora/classes/rtcengine.html#joinchannel)

You will receive this uid on the receiver's side while listening to ["stream-added"](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.client.html#on) event on the web and ["userJoined"](https://syanbo.github.io/react-native-agora/classes/rtcengine.html#on) event on the React Native